# JSF | is there a way to change the value of a Bean field while exiting the current page?

Tags: jsf

so I'm trying to set a boolean value to false if I am leaving the current page, is there a way to do this purely with JSF? I take JavaScript too, but I would prefer a pure JSF solution.

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
                () => window.onunload = terminateTutorial;
            );
            
            const terminateTutorial = () =>{
                document.getElementById('toogleTutorialmode').click();
            }
        </script>
        
        <p:commandButton style="visibility: hidden" id="toogleTutorialmode" action="#{tutorial.setTutorialMode(false)}"/>
```

But it didnt work.

Hope its possible.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I tried it, but it didn't work either. Do you know if the problem could be that the code I posted above is inside a layout that is used throughout the application, so it's never “exited”?

Comment: Your example is not a [mcve]. For example, a form is missing. Have a close look at the duplicates and find the differences.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: it's generally too late to fire a HTTP request during unload because connection is already closed. It might work during beforeunload.